# Using JavaScript/jQuery to convert content of TextArea to plain text before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, forms

I have the following form

```
        <form action=“/animals/living” method="POST">
            <input name=“cat” placeholder=“cat name”><br/>
            <input name=“dog” placeholder=“dog name”><br/>
            <input name=“bunny” placeholder=“bunny name”><br/>
            Description:<textarea name="description" placeholder="Description" rows="2"
                                  cols="50"></textarea>
            Documentation:<br/><textarea name="documentation" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea><br/>
            Essay:<br/> <textarea name=“essays” rows="8" cols="80"></textarea><br/>
            Passage:<br/> <textarea name=“passage” rows="8" cols="80"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
```

Before I submit the form I want to change all the content of the `TextArea`s to plainText. I find a jQuery function that supposedly can do it.

```
var my_plaintext = $(the_richtext).text();
```

So my question is this:

How do I apply the jQuery function to the textAreas contents and then submit the form?

(In case you were still wondering, the content of a TextArea is in RichText format.)

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()`, `.submit()`

Comment: Will you please do me the kindness of merging my form with your suggestion? I may be too novice to understand how to apply your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault()`, `.val()`, `.submit()`

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("textarea", this).val(function(i, value) {
      return $("<div/>",{text:value}).text();
   });
   this.submit();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. So do I have to modify my form in any way? (I am extremely new to html.)

Comment: Should not have to modify `html`, you should be able to try at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks. It sends the form but the textarea payload is still rich text as opposed to plain text.

Comment: @KatedralPillon Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?